# How can I make my bot delete its own message?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I am making a clear command. When the messages get deleted, the bot gives a message saying the messages were deleted. After 1 second, I want it to delete that message. 
I know how to get that delay of 1 second. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store sent messages in a variable and use asyncio's sleep function for the delay, or `delete()`'s kwarg, `delay`:

```py
@bot.command()
async def disappear(ctx):
    msg = await ctx.send("Hey!")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    await msg.delete()
```

And the kwarg:

```py
@bot.command()
async def disappear(ctx):
    msg = await ctx.send("Hey!")
    await msg.delete(delay=1)
```

---

**References:**

- [`asyncio.sleep`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#sleeping)
- [`Message.delete()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.delete)